# deserializing with naming change for all properties

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-namespaces, datacontractserializer

I try to deserialize xml.
My serializer expects this format:

```
<GetItemTransactionsResponse xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eBay.Service.Core.Soap" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:mAck>Warning</a:mAck>
        <a:mAckSpecified>true</a:mAckSpecified>
        <a:mAny i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
        <a:mBotBlock i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mBuild>915</a:mBuild>
        <a:mCorrelationID i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mDuplicateInvocationDetails i:nil="true"/>
        <a:mEIASToken i:nil="true"/>
```

And i want it to expect this format:

```
<GetItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
      <Timestamp>2008-02-13T03:47:28.106Z</Timestamp>
      <Ack>Success</Ack>
      <CorrelationID>137541140</CorrelationID>
      <Version>553</Version>
      <Build>e553_core_Bundled_6057805_R1</Build>
      <NotificationEventName>ItemSold</NotificationEventName>
      <RecipientUserID>Seller1</RecipientUserID>
      <Item>
```

To tell it to support the second format instead of the first i need to tell it to:

1. Use the right namespace. (i think i can handle)
2. Remove the m at the begining for every attribute. (my bigger problem)

I prefer using DataContractSerializer, but its not a must.

Thank you for your help

Dolev

Comment: Do you have a specific question or are you asking us to write this for you?

Comment: Going from xml to xml is not deserialization; can you clarify what you want to do? is this a refactor? or...?

Comment: I try to deserialize the second format, and it complains that it does not have the mAck property (Like i have in the first format). meaning i need to remove the m at the beginning of each property...

Comment: The first format is what it expects with the deserialization(somewhy...), and i want it to recieve as input the second format.

Comment: What does your class look like?  I assume your XML actually looks like this: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/guides/ebayfeatures/Notifications/Notif-ItemSold.html

Comment: The ebay notification is what i recieve as 3rd party. i try to deserialize it myself, But it expect the first format, and i need to support the second format. I only want to focus on the deserialization part instead of looking on the entire wcf, and i want to know why it expects the above format and how do i set it like the bottom one.